# Plone Gazatte throwing traceback when adding newsletter in newsletter theme

Tags: plone

I am using Plone 4.1.3. I installed PloneGazatte product without any mount points, it was working fine. In the same version, I created **mount points** and installed the product. When I create a newsletter in the newsletter theme it is throwing traceback errors.

Can anyone help me how to solve these errors?

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPythonScript, line 105, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.Script, line 145, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 130, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 31, in createObject
   - <FSControllerPythonScript at /en/indg.in/createObject used for /en/indg.in/indg-newsletter>
   - Line 31
  Module Products.CMFCore.PortalFolder, line 295, in invokeFactory
  Module Products.CMFCore.TypesTool, line 835, in constructContent
  Module Products.CMFCore.TypesTool, line 313, in constructInstance
  Module Products.CMFCore.TypesTool, line 554, in _constructInstance
  Module Products.PloneGazette.Newsletter, line 81, in addNewsletter
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 356, in _setObject
  Module zope.event, line 31, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.event, line 32, in objectEventNotify
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module Products.CMFCore.CMFCatalogAware, line 265, in handleContentishEvent
  Module Products.CMFCore.CMFCatalogAware, line 191, in notifyWorkflowCreated
  Module Products.CMFCore.WorkflowTool, line 292, in notifyCreated
  Module Products.CMFCore.WorkflowTool, line 638, in _reindexWorkflowVariables
  Module Products.CMFCore.CMFCatalogAware, line 91, in reindexObject
  Module Products.CMFCore.CatalogTool, line 304, in reindexObject
  Module Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool, line 387, in catalog_object
  Module Products.ZCatalog.ZCatalog, line 476, in catalog_object
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 322, in catalogObject
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 272, in updateMetadata
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 396, in recordify
  Module plone.indexer.wrapper, line 59, in __getattr__
  Module plone.indexer.delegate, line 16, in __call__
  Module plone.contentratings.catalog, line 20, in average_rating
  Module plone.contentratings.catalog, line 9, in _first_user_rating
  Module contentratings.browser.aggregator, line 8, in get_rating_categories
  Module contentratings.browser.aggregator, line 8, in <genexpr>
  Module zope.component.registry, line 250, in getAdapters
  Module contentratings.category, line 69, in __call__
  Module zope.component._api, line 120, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module zope.component.registry, line 238, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 532, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module contentratings.category, line 102, in __init__
  Module contentratings.category, line 121, in _lookup_or_create_storage
TypeError: ('Could not adapt', <Newsletter at /en/indg.in/indg-newsletter/newsletter.2012-06-26.1477811319>, <InterfaceClass zope.annotation.interfaces.IAnnotations>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like plone.contentratings is incompatible with PloneGazette. plone.contentratings assumes here that it can annotate the Newsletter, but it fails to check if Newsletter can be adapted to the IAnnotation interface.

I would say this needs a fix in plone.contentratings (or its dependency contentratings). But I would also expect that PloneGazette can be adapted, so probably it can be fixed there as well.

I would suggest to find the bug trackers for these two packages and file a bug there.  Or hope that one of the authors reads this stackoverflow question.

Comment: Maurtis i don't think so, it is because of plone.contentratings. I have tested the same in my localhost it is working fine.